# Continuous function and a related infimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, functions

Let $f : [a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(a) = 0$ and assume that there is some $x' \in ( a, b)$ such that $f(x') > 0$. Denote by
$$
x_0 := \inf \{ x \in [ a, b) : f ( x ) > 0 \}.
$$

> Show that
>
> $1.$ $f(x_0) = 0$
>
> $2.$ There is a sequence $x_n \downarrow x_0$ such that $f ( x_n ) > 0$.

It is easy to see that $a \leq x_0 \leq x'$ and if $x_0 = a$ then the first claim is obvious. If $x_0 \neq a$, then by the definition of infimum, $f \leq 0$ on $[a, x_0)$ and by the continuity of $f$ we get $f(x_0) \leq 0$. Now, if the second claim is true, then the continuity of $f$ would also imply that $f(x_0) \geq0$ and so $f(x_0)=0$.

How to show the second claim? If no such sequence exists, then $f \leq 0$ on $[ x_0, \varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, but by the definition of infimum, there should exits some $\varepsilon_0$ such that $x_0 \leq \varepsilon_0 < \varepsilon$ with $f(\varepsilon_0) >0$, which leads to a contradiction. Is this correct? Is there maybe a shorter argument?

Answer (score 1):

For the first claim, assume $x_0 > a$, one get that if $f(x_0) >0$, by the continuity there exists $\epsilon$ s.t. $x_0 - \epsilon > a, f(x_0 - \epsilon) > 0$, which make a contradictory. The proof is similar if we assume $f(x_0) < 0$. For the second claim, one can prove that there exists $x_1 \in (x_0, \frac {x_0 + x’} {2})$ s.t. $f(x_1 )> 0$, otherwise the inf will be no less than $\frac {x_0 + x’} {2}$. Repeat the procedure and we will get such sequence in claim 2.

Comment: In your proof, don't you first need to show that $x_0 < x'$?

Comment: @Holden Yes, while the proof is also trivial.